# Thread in C just halting execution?

Tags: c

I have a robot that I am controlling through a specific library with C.

I need a thread that checks if a button is pressed, and if it is, the program exits.

This check should happen separated from the main thread, so that I can run the robot movement code along with the button check code.

I've made a small PoC but it's not working: the program flow halts and the button check is executed indefinitely.

Here is the code. If some variables/functions are missing in this snippet, don't worry, they are there in the actual code.

```
void *brick_controller(void *vargp){
    printf("Second thread is working!\n");
    uint8_t button_buffer;
    while(true)
    {
        size_t result = ev3_read_keys(&button_buffer);
        //printf("ass %d\n", buf);
        if(button_buffer == 32){
            exit(666);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf( "Waiting the EV3 brick online...\n" );
    if ( ev3_init() < 1 ) return ( 1 );

    printf( "*** ( EV3 ) Hello! ASS ***\n" );
    ev3_sensor_init();
    ev3_tacho_init();

    app_alive = app_init();
    if (app_alive == 0)
    {
        /*int distance = 250;
        if (argc == 1)
        {} 
        else if (argc == 2)
        {
            default_speed = atoi(argv[1]);
        } 
        else if (argc == 3)
        {
            default_speed = atoi(argv[1]);
            distance = atoi(argv[2]);
        }
        else {
            printf("Too many arguments!\n");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Speed:%d\n"
                "Distance:%d\n", default_speed, distance);
        drive(default_speed, distance);
        */
        pthread_create(&brick_controller_thread, NULL, *brick_controller, NULL); 
        pthread_join(brick_controller_thread, NULL); 

        int i = 0;
        while(i < 200){ // This never executes :(
            i++;
            printf("All is running! %d\n", i); 
        }

    } else {
        printf("App initialization failed! Error code: %d\n", app_alive);
        return 2;
    }

    ev3_uninit();
    return 0;
```

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read more about [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) and what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) page:

> The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread
>          to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then
>          pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by thread
>          must be joinable.

`pthread_join` waits for the thread to terminate, which never will.

Comment: You should not place `pthread_join` there since you do not want to wait for the `thread` to exit at this point.

Comment: You want to exit `main()` using `pthread_exit()` instead of `return`, else when `main()` ends all other threads of the process will be ended as well the moment `main()` ends.